# Command Prompt missing from Windows Server 2000 Advanced Server

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, windows-2000

I'm trying to remotely get IP info from this machine however I've noticed that command prompt is missing from it (run is also missing). I'm not able to access the C driver as that's been disallowed.

Any idea how I could get cmd.exe on this machine without downloading any software?

OS: Windows 2000 Advanced Server

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to stack overflow and a little with command prompt but I can probably help you to get cmd.exe back. Type the following in notepad and save as a batch file (.bat)
First method:

cmd.exe

second method:

@echo off
Title command prompt
ver
echo this works omg
echo
:x
set /p the="%cd%>"
%the%
echo
goto x

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).